# React-native ListView "Warning: Can't call setState"

Tags: android, listview, react-native, warnings, react-navigation

hey guys could someone please look over this. I cant find where its comming from i've been looking on this page the last days and i cant find it

the Problem is everytime when i`m clicking on one of the names in the list the navigation and the Transver of the Values to "global.dialed" works perfektly but im always getting this warning and the app seems to perform a little slower after that (but the slower performance is very minor and probably just an illusion)

Full error:

```
Warning: Can't call setState (or forceUpdate) on an unmounted component. 
This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, 
cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount 
method.
```

stacktrace is pointing to line 25

#### RecentCalls.js:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Text, View, ListView, TouchableHighlight } from "react-native";
import styles from "./../Styles/styles";
import global from "./../Components/global";

export default class RecentCalls extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    const ds = new ListView.DataSource({
      rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2
    });
    this.state = {
      userDataSource: ds
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchUsers();
  }

  fetchUsers() {
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({
          userDataSource: this.state.userDataSource.cloneWithRows(response)
        });
      });
  }

  onPress(user) {
    this.props.navigation.navigate("Home3", {});
    global.dialed = user.phone;
  }

  renderRow(user, sectionId, rowId, highlightRow) {
    return (
      <TouchableHighlight
        onPress={() => {
          this.onPress(user);
        }}
      >
        <View style={[styles.row]}>
          <Text style={[styles.rowText]}>
            {user.name}: {user.phone}
          </Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableHighlight>
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.padding2}>
        <ListView
          dataSource={this.state.userDataSource}
          renderRow={this.renderRow.bind(this)}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

### Thank you very much for your Time and effort in advance :)

#### edit 1

according to [milkersarac](https://stackoverflow.com/users/218198/milkersarac) I Tried (See below) but it made no difference

edited Constructor to:

```
  constructor() {
    super();
    const ds = new ListView.DataSource({
      rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2
    });
    this.state = {
      userDataSource: ds
    };
    this.fetchUsers = this.fetchUsers.bind(this);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to `.bind(this)` the function that you are updating component state in your components' constructor. Namely try adding `this.fetchUsers = this.fetchUsers.bind(this)` as the last line to your ctor.

Comment: Tried (See Question#Edit1) but sadly it made no difference